Getting an import error when importing matplotlib module
Error message
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:156: UserWarning: The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time). This can in some cases result in small but subtle issues and is discouraged.
  import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malith/Documents/Assignments/python - software project/code/q.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

Here is my code with the import.
Code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_letter_distribution(s):
    letter_counts = letter_count(s)
    letters = list(letter_counts.keys())
    counts = list(letter_counts.values())

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.bar(letters, counts)
    plt.xlabel('Letters')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('Letter Distribution')
    plt.show()

Error is coming from the matplotlib import. Does anyone know the potential issue here. I have already installed the numpy and matplot lib packages too.

Can you do pip freeze and report the results?

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4982 I'd look at the solutions in issues like this. there are two PILs, PIL and Pillow, and you want to make sure you only have Pillow installed

Does this answer your question? ImportError: cannot import name _imaging

no, it doesn't worked for me,

THe issue has been fixed by creating a virtual environment and in their I installed matplotlib and it worked without an issue.
